# Appending arrays in python gives weird formatting

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm currently trying to parse through large csv files by using chunks with pandas and read_csv() in python. However, when I add all the rows from the chunk to an array and print the array, the formatting seems off for each item in the array (or essentially each array in the array). I have the following code:

```
chunksize = 10
data = []

for chunk in pd.read_csv("testData.csv", chunksize=chunksize):
    for value in chunk.values:
        data.append(value)
    print(data)
```

gives me the following output:

> "[array(['WSPY', 'PKYJ', 62048, 96988], dtype=object), array(['QHWL',
> 'PXWE', 77146, 70056], dtype=object), array(['RSMQ', 'YLSK', 19495,
> 76992], dtype=object),...]

As opposed to:

> [['WSPY', 'PKYJ', 62048, 96988], ['QHWL', 'PXWE', 77146, 70056],
> ['RSMQ', 'YLSK', 19495, 76992], ...]

Is there a reason why the formatting would be different and how I could fix that?

Comment: Does `data.append(value.tolist())` solve your problem?

Comment: `values` from a dataframe is an array

Comment: `chunk.values` returns a numpy array. But if the CSV file is so large that it can't fit into a DataFrame, what good does a list do for you?

Answer (score 0):

From your display, I reconstructed a dataframe:

```
In [71]: [np.array(['WSPY', 'PKYJ', 62048, 96988], dtype=object), np.array(['QHW
    ...: L', 'PXWE', 77146, 70056], dtype=object), np.array(['RSMQ', 'YLSK', 194
    ...: 95, 76992], dtype=object)]
Out[71]: 
[array(['WSPY', 'PKYJ', 62048, 96988], dtype=object),
 array(['QHWL', 'PXWE', 77146, 70056], dtype=object),
 array(['RSMQ', 'YLSK', 19495, 76992], dtype=object)]

In [74]: df = pd.DataFrame(_71)
In [75]: df
Out[75]: 
      0     1      2      3
0  WSPY  PKYJ  62048  96988
1  QHWL  PXWE  77146  70056
2  RSMQ  YLSK  19495  76992
```

Because of the mix of string and numeric data, the `values` array is object dtype

```
In [81]: df.values
Out[81]: 
array([['WSPY', 'PKYJ', 62048, 96988],
       ['QHWL', 'PXWE', 77146, 70056],
       ['RSMQ', 'YLSK', 19495, 76992]], dtype=object)
```

and with the chunked kind of iteration, we get a list of 1d object arrays, one for each row of the dataframe:

```
In [82]: data = []
    ...: for value in df.values:
    ...:     data.append(value)
    ...: 
In [83]: data
Out[83]: 
[array(['WSPY', 'PKYJ', 62048, 96988], dtype=object),
 array(['QHWL', 'PXWE', 77146, 70056], dtype=object),
 array(['RSMQ', 'YLSK', 19495, 76992], dtype=object)]
```

the dataframe values could be made into a list of lists:

```
In [89]: df.values.tolist()
Out[89]: 
[['WSPY', 'PKYJ', 62048, 96988],
 ['QHWL', 'PXWE', 77146, 70056],
 ['RSMQ', 'YLSK', 19495, 76992]]
```

Usually in Python, formatting of objects is supposed to mean something, showing us the identity as well as values of the object.  List formatting is simplest. `numpy` arrays formatting can be simple if the dtype is numeric, but becomes more complicated with it contains `objects`, no numeric elements.  As you learn the language you'll learn to read to display as well.